# How to invoke input-validation-error for a dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to implement validation for required field for a textbox and a dropdownlist. Here is the code:
For textbox:

```
@Html.Label("Part/Location", new {@class = "control-label"})
@Html.TextBox("PartLocation", null, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

for Dropdownlist:

```
 @Html.Label("Location", new {@class = "control-label"})
 @Html.DropDownList("DirectionTypes", null, "-- Select Direction --", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

When I click a button to submit without typing any input in the textbox and selecting in dropdownlist, the textbox invokes input-validation-error  and has brown border around the textbox but the dropdownlist doesnt. Both have attribute required = "required". So, how can I have the same effect for the dropdown list?

Comment: Show the model with the validation attributes

Comment: This dropdownlist is hard coded one. Is there any other way?

Comment: Either way, you're hard coding it by filling your `DirectionTypes`, right?

Comment: Your using MVC. Why not take advantage of its features including client and server side validation (applying the `[Required]` attribute t the property and using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in conjunction with jquery.validate.unobtrusive)

Comment: @minhnguyen did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In your model that has `DirectionTypes`, consider adding an `int` key (perhaps `DirectionTypeID`?):

```
[Required]
public int DirectionTypeID { get; set; }
```

Then you can use `@Html.DropDownListFor` like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DirectionTypeID, 
                           DirectionTypes, 
                           "-- Select Direction --", 
                           new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```